# Nestjs start fails silently in module initialization

Tags: express, nestjs

Running `nest start`

The module initialization fails silently without error at `const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);`

This seems to fail after the CqrsModule dependency is initialized. I dont see anything in the logger I have setup, would this be reported anywhere else?

[image]

It quits directly after the last line above.

Comment: remove node modules and reinstall it.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was using a newer version of node. Once I switched to the original node version in my project, I started getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it after realising that I had a service that was calling itself in its constructor.

Once removed, everything started working back as usual.